# Is there a command to get packet loss rate on WiFi interface

Tags: wireless

I'm wondering if it is possible to know the packet (or frame) drop rate on a specific WiFi interface, at mac layer so without using any upper layer network measurement tools ?

Answer (score 3):

Try: `cat /proc/net/wireless`

Example output:

```
Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |   Discarded packets               | Missed | WE
 face | tus | link level noise |  nwid  crypt   frag  retry   misc | beacon | 22
wlp5s1: 0000   49.  -61.  -256        0      0      0   8673   3336        0
```

Comment: I thought maybe the weird formatting was a result of having copied the result from a too-small terminal but no, it actually looks like that

Answer (score 2):

I think `wavemon` is a nice tool to monitor wifi quality. I am not exactly sure if `mac retries`, `invalid`, `missed beacons` are the figures that you are looking for. Give it a try.

What about `/sbin/ifconfig`. I think it also shows the number of dropped packets.

Comment: `wavemon` is the way to go, that's really cool